# Joomla HTML validation

Tags: html, validation, joomla

I am trying to validate the home page of my Joomla. The issue is that I have the site on my local host so I can not simply copy the URL into http://validator.w3.org/ to validate.

My next thought was to open the index page in my browser and then run firebug to access the source code, and then copy and paste the code into the validator.

This seemed to work okay however when the code returns errors, I now don't know where to access the html to correct them.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can have a look at web developper extension, you can validate local pages with it

Comment: You can get browser extensions that integrate with validator.w3.org. Simply do a 2 second Google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not much knowledge about the way Joomla works, you will have to learn about the file locations.

Normaly, most changes should be done on the `index.php` file located in your template folder (`root/templates/name_of_your_template/index.php`)

If the changes you need to make aren't located in this file, you can have a look at the modules, component or plugin files that output these error and that becomes more serious.

If there is a template override for the module/component/plugin you need to modify, the files should be located in `root/templates/name_of_your_template/html/name_of_the_module_component_or_plugin`

If there is no template overide for the module/component/plugin that outputs the error, you will have to learn about template overrides.

Comment: Thanks,  I did look at the index.php file but it does not contain the error I am receiving. I have validated the template css file and that was fine but I will have a look at the modules, I guess I will need to look at each of the individual modules I am including on the page, is that correct?

Comment: @user3110441 Well, you can try identifying the concerned extension that creates errors using firebug and then search for it's files.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser, there are many extensions that will validate non-accessible (i.e. localhost) pages

In Google Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-validator/cgndfbhngibokieehnjhbjkkhbfmhojo?hl=en

Once it's installed, click on the icon and validate local page.

Comment: Not sure if you can unselect an answer but if this helps please accept my answer instead.